# Use associated model scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have a model called `User` that `has_many :games` and games `has_many :events`- How can I get all the users which do not have any games OR have any games with a suspended event.

Here is what I have tried:

Example:

User class:

```
scope :with_no_games -> {
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN games g on g.user_id = users.id").where("games.id IS NULL")
}  

scope :with_suspended_games_or_no_games -> {
  with_no_games.merge(Game.suspended) # <- this doesn't work
}
```

Game class:

```
scope :suspended -> {
  joins("INNER JOIN events e ON event.game_id = games.id AND event.name = 'suspended'")
}
```

If I run `User.with_suspended_games_or_no_games` I get the following SQL statement:

`SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" LEFT OUTER JOIN games ON games.user_id = users.id INNER JOIN events ON events.game_id = games.id AND events.name = 'suspended' WHERE (games.user_id IS NULL)"`

Which is not what I am looking for. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the error and what does the generated SQL query look like?

Comment: Added generated SQL - It does not error out, but it just does not return what I expect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
scope :with_suspended_games_or_no_games -> {
  with_no_games.joins(:games).merge(Game.suspended)
}
```

to see the sql try running the following from a rails console:

```
User.with_suspended_games_or_no_games.to_sql
```

**bonus**

you could also write your scopes like:

**User**

```
scope :with_no_games -> { joins(:games).where(games: {id: nil}) }
scope :with_suspended_games_or_no_games -> { joins(:games).with_no_games.merge(Game.suspended) }
```

**Game**

```
scope :suspended -> { joins(:events).where(events: {name: 'suspended'}) }
```

Comment: That merge is not doing what I want. Here is the SQL that it does:
`"SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" LEFT OUTER JOIN games ON games.user_id = users.id INNER JOIN events ON events.game_id = games.id AND events.name = 'declined' WHERE (games.user_id IS NULL)"`